# Can I programmatically extract data from superset virtual datasets

Tags: apache-superset

Can this be done via a REST API or better yet some SQL-type connection to Superset?

If my team invests in building data models in superset I'd like to be able to expose them to programming languages like python for further data wrangling and downstream systems, rather than just display them on charts.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the virtual dataset  using `/dataset/export` endpoint then expose the data to other applications.